# Faster loading time for react in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react in the browser. It works fine, but it's not fast enough. The initial load takes too much time while it compiles.

I'd like to use react/jsx in the browser and have it compile on the fly without introducing a build step via webpack or using "create-react-app". I find these things to be too much of a process for what I need. Sometimes I just need to write a quick little utility that doesn't need to take more than one (html) file and I'd like to to throw that one file on a static server.

The single-file-example below works but unfortunately the loading time is just too slow. Maybe someone found a creative way to cache things or make things faster? Maybe there's no way around the first time it loads, but how about the second time etc? maybe an intermediary server can compile+cache it, so that subsequent requests would be faster. not sure. Or maybe there's a super fast babel that I'm not aware of that could just work faster than the below?

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/master/static/html/single-file-example.html

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );

    </script>

  </body>
```

Comment: You should be hosting build files, not using babel to read your JS every time. Babel can output transpiled files to use in production. However, bundlers like webpack or parcel can do more things like minification and uglification.

Comment: @SimeonSmith yes I know the correct way to do this would be with webpack, but I'm looking for a hack. I don't want to use webpack.

Comment: Like I mentioned, babel can create the transpiled files. It will output them so babel does not have to interpret them every time.
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli.html#compile-files

Comment: *I'm looking for a hack* -- this will be really difficult, especially as you want to do compilation on the fly, it will incur speed loss on client side... like, evertime.

Comment: @SimeonSmith interesting.. so it works like webpack (?)

Comment: How would redis make client side anything faster? This is the same discussion we had earlier-you're working against pretty much everything, and you will always pay the price, whether it's dependency management or transpiling on the client side.

Comment: @DaveNewton I know that. what's the point of arguing that though. lol. I mentioned redis as a possible way to cache transpiled files on the fly.

Comment: Redis on the client side?! Taking browser-compiled files and caching them? I don't even understand what you're trying to do, or why. That would be significantly more complex than just delivering what the client can use.

Comment: Umm... Node.js would be on the server-side, so at that point you might as well compile on the server-side. You could do something with caching the compiled code in localStorage or something, but then you do away with the benefits of compiling on the fly.

Comment: @foreyez It will transpile the files into browser friendly JavaScript. Then if you serve those you don't have to use babel on the client side. I've been using this currently for a different scripts in Google Sheets. Using ES6+ JavaScript and transpiling to script that Google Sheets likes.

Comment: @foreyez, Why don't you want to use Webpack or a build step?

Comment: @SimeonSmith I find the whole thing a bit "too much". I like how react works, but I don't want to introduce a build step to my code. Especially when I deal with like 1 or 2 files and I do really small utilities.

Comment: @froeyez Is it the setup that you feel is "too much"? If so, you could always try `create-react-app` to automate setup.

Comment: Look at ParcelJS. It's a no config alternative to Webpack. It also provides a development server with hot reloading when you save files. That makes compile a ton faster when you're developing. Or create-react-app like @NorianNyx suggested.

Comment: @NorianNyx that's what I've been using. but I don't like it. my create-react-app is hundreds of megabytes and the build process is a pain. I don't need all that. I'd like to use react just like I used to use jquery. ie, just add one file to my html file. I understand that jsx is an entirely different language and needs to be compiled, I like the example they gave of react in the browser but it's just not fast enough.

Comment: @foreyez Then just use the CDN. https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html.

Comment: Also, checkout the babel watch section in my initial link. That way you can just reload the browser when you change a file and save it.

Comment: @foreyez You only need to compile if you are using JSX (and that will probably always be the case). There is a pure vanilla JS way to use React, you just have to create components in a more verbose way.

Comment: You simply cannot use React like you used jQuery-it is a completely different animal. "yarn build" really isn't that hard. I'm not convinced React is really what you want-everything discussed is more complex than CRA. I mean, you *could* get rid of much of the stuff CRA gives you, like es6 features you're not using, eslint, etc. Anything you're going to do in the browser will need some of that too, though, and be slower to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Pulling answer from comments.

Use `npx babel script.js --watch --out-file script-compiled.js` to compile your files and load those files. You will be required to reload to update the site.

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli.html#compile-files

Comment: I think npx babel is outdated. they have this thing called babel-cli. but your idea is interesting. it's still a server-side compilation but it's alot less than webpack. it might be good for single files. I don't have alot of dependencies in my code. so I will check this out further.

Comment: @foreyez npx would be used if you don't install babel-cli globally. That is using the babel-cli and is the recommendation straight from babel's site.

Comment: Using npx allows you to take your code from one computer to another without having to install any npm packages globally. This way the project is independent of global npm packages.